# How to draw only corner of a square in flutter

Tags: flutter, rounded-corners, cornerradius

I wish to have a similar result at the corners of the image. But I don't find any solution with the Container and the decoration. Do you have a suggestion?

[image: qr code image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can try with `CustomPaint`

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, I have extracted from the [qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) QR scan library (now deprecated, use [mobile_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner) instead) the overlay it offers and I have modified it so that it does not obscure the outside of the square. This way you can apply the overlay to whatever feature you want.

**Desired Class**

```
Stack(
        children: [
          ...,
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Container(
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                shape: QrScannerOverlayShape(
                  borderColor: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: 10,
                  borderLength: 20,
                  borderWidth: 5,
                  cutOutSize: scanArea,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ...,
        ],
),
```

**QrScannerOverlayShape Class**

```
class QrScannerOverlayShape extends ShapeBorder {
  QrScannerOverlayShape({
    this.borderColor = Colors.red,
    this.borderWidth = 3.0,
    this.overlayColor = const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 80),
    this.borderRadius = 0,
    this.borderLength = 40,
    double? cutOutSize,
    double? cutOutWidth,
    double? cutOutHeight,
    this.cutOutBottomOffset = 0,
  })  : cutOutWidth = cutOutWidth ?? cutOutSize ?? 250,
        cutOutHeight = cutOutHeight ?? cutOutSize ?? 250 {
    assert(
    borderLength <=
        min(this.cutOutWidth, this.cutOutHeight) / 2 + borderWidth * 2,
    "Border can't be larger than ${min(this.cutOutWidth, this.cutOutHeight) / 2 + borderWidth * 2}",
    );
    assert(
    (cutOutWidth == null && cutOutHeight == null) ||
        (cutOutSize == null && cutOutWidth != null && cutOutHeight != null),
    'Use only cutOutWidth and cutOutHeight or only cutOutSize');
  }

  final Color borderColor;
  final double borderWidth;
  final Color overlayColor;
  final double borderRadius;
  final double borderLength;
  final double cutOutWidth;
  final double cutOutHeight;
  final double cutOutBottomOffset;

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => const EdgeInsets.all(10);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Path()
      ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd
      ..addPath(getOuterPath(rect), Offset.zero);
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    Path getLeftTopPath(Rect rect) {
      return Path()
        ..moveTo(rect.left, rect.bottom)
        ..lineTo(rect.left, rect.top)
        ..lineTo(rect.right, rect.top);
    }

    return getLeftTopPath(rect)
      ..lineTo(
        rect.right,
        rect.bottom,
      )
      ..lineTo(
        rect.left,
        rect.bottom,
      )
      ..lineTo(
        rect.left,
        rect.top,
      );
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    final width = rect.width;
    final borderWidthSize = width / 2;
    final height = rect.height;
    final borderOffset = borderWidth / 2;
    final mBorderLength =
    borderLength > min(cutOutHeight, cutOutHeight) / 2 + borderWidth * 2
        ? borderWidthSize / 2
        : borderLength;
    final mCutOutWidth =
    cutOutWidth < width ? cutOutWidth : width - borderOffset;
    final mCutOutHeight =
    cutOutHeight < height ? cutOutHeight : height - borderOffset;

    final backgroundPaint = Paint()
      ..color = overlayColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final borderPaint = Paint()
      ..color = borderColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = borderWidth;

    final boxPaint = Paint()
      ..color = borderColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.dstOut;

    final cutOutRect = Rect.fromLTWH(
      rect.left + width / 2 - mCutOutWidth / 2 + borderOffset,
      -cutOutBottomOffset +
          rect.top +
          height / 2 -
          mCutOutHeight / 2 +
          borderOffset,
      mCutOutWidth - borderOffset * 2,
      mCutOutHeight - borderOffset * 2,
    );

    canvas
      ..saveLayer(
        rect,
        backgroundPaint,
      )
    // ..drawRect(
    //   rect,
    //   backgroundPaint,
    // )
    // Draw top right corner
      ..drawRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
          cutOutRect.right - mBorderLength,
          cutOutRect.top,
          cutOutRect.right,
          cutOutRect.top + mBorderLength,
          topRight: Radius.circular(borderRadius),
        ),
        borderPaint,
      )
    // Draw top left corner
      ..drawRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
          cutOutRect.left,
          cutOutRect.top,
          cutOutRect.left + mBorderLength,
          cutOutRect.top + mBorderLength,
          topLeft: Radius.circular(borderRadius),
        ),
        borderPaint,
      )
    // Draw bottom right corner
      ..drawRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
          cutOutRect.right - mBorderLength,
          cutOutRect.bottom - mBorderLength,
          cutOutRect.right,
          cutOutRect.bottom,
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(borderRadius),
        ),
        borderPaint,
      )
    // Draw bottom left corner
      ..drawRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
          cutOutRect.left,
          cutOutRect.bottom - mBorderLength,
          cutOutRect.left + mBorderLength,
          cutOutRect.bottom,
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(borderRadius),
        ),
        borderPaint,
      )
      ..drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
          cutOutRect,
          Radius.circular(borderRadius),
        ),
        boxPaint,
      )
      ..restore();
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    return QrScannerOverlayShape(
      borderColor: borderColor,
      borderWidth: borderWidth,
      overlayColor: overlayColor,
    );
  }
}
```

Tip: If you uncomment the commented section of code, it will show the outside of the square darkened.

```
 ..drawRect(
   rect,
   backgroundPaint,
 )
```

**How it looks** (red color and obscure background chosen)

[image]